# Android UI design - Create a custom category list

Tags: android, user-interface

Ho can I design a page like this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this layout simply make a `GridView` with custom layout. The custom layout could contains two child `LinearLayout` and The desired `ImageView` and `TextView` inside them. If you aren't familier with custom `GridView` just have a look on the simple tutorial,

https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-gridview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html

For designing the layout see the below image,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a gridView or RecyclerView(with a gridLayoutManager) and each item in your grid will contain properties like name,image,bgcolor1,bgcolor2 ..desing a layout and change the color,image name at runtime..